# Minify and Unminify js based on working enviroment

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify

I have large js file approx 800kB (un-minified) and 100KB (Minified).In production environment i minify it online every time and unminify it again in development environment manually.Is there any way to automated this task.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Write a script for it?

Comment: There are many ways :D What backend do you use (Java/PHP/...?)

Comment: If you're on nodejs environment, check out http://gruntjs.com/

Comment: Please state what environment you're using. Visual Studio? Eclipse?

Comment: I am php,jquery and angularjs with netbeans

Answer (score 0):

If you want a build-time solution (your statics are minified when you package your application), I think that:

- it's not mandatory to use [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) on top of node.js only if your application is developed with  node.js (for instance [jhipster](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster) is a java project which uses node.js)
- it's also not mandatory to use [WUIC](http://wuic.github.io/) on top of maven if your application is developed with JAVA. For instance, WUIC web site is itself a full static project packaged with maven.

If you use netbeans, you should note that it provides a good maven integration support.